FireFox cutting of absolutely positioned elements
I'm developing an Angular app at work. I noticed position absolute on firefox is cutting off  about 5px from the top of the absolutely positioned element. I have this.
<div class="features-title-box">
    <p class="background-text background-text-light" [class.firefox]="isFirefox">AGENCIES</p>
    <h2 class="features-title features-title-light">Fast-Track Your Hiring Process</h2>
</div>

.background-text {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 15rem;
            font-weight: 900;
            width: 100%;
            color: rgba($secondary100, 0.3);
            white-space: nowrap;
            z-index: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            line-height: 12rem;
            top: 0;

            &.firefox {
                line-height: 15rem;
                top: -5px;
            }

            &-light {
                color: rgba($secondary50, 0.2);
            }
        }

        .features-title {
            font-size: 2.8rem;
            color: $textDark;
            z-index: 20;
            width: 100%;
            text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 0.3rem 0.8rem;

            &-light {
                color: $textLight;
            }
        }
    }

Only on firefox does the top get cut off so I added firefox specific styles but this is a hack. I've noticed this behavior on another small component. This does not happen on Chrome or Edge.
here is a code sandbox. You can see the difference in alignment when you open this on chrome or any other browser compared to firefox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/firefox-absolute-positioning-3fjj8t?file=%2Fstyles.css%3A24%2C16

Please show us details of the actual reason and their cause - you'll find these in the Layout/Computed pane of both Chrome+Firefox's DevTools. Otherwise your post has communicated nothing of value.

I use rem units at the root of my app. I set font-size to 62.5% making 1 rem = 10px. This can't be the issue though because I see it in another component in my component library where I only use px units (not rem). It's only present in Firefox
